# How to reference a variable in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm new to ansible. I can't get the answer in ansible website.
How to reference a variable in ansible playbook? eg:

```
- name: Set schedulability
  hosts: oo_first_master
  vars:
    install_nodes: "{{ hostvars
                         | oo_select_keys(groups['oo_nodes_to_config'])
                         | oo_collect('open.common.hostname') }}"
    install_node_vars: "{{ hostvars | oo_select_keys(groups['oo_nodes_to_config']) }}"
```

Seen "install_nodes" refered to like this:

```
- name: Wait for Node Registration
  command: >
      {{ install.common.client_binary }} get node {{ item | lower }}
  register: omd_get_node
  until: omd_get_node.rc == 0
  retries: 20
  delay: 5
  changed_when: false
  with_items: install_nodes
```

I think reference a variable should be involed with "{{ }}" in ansible playbook. But it's referenced directly. How many way to reference variables in ansible?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`when`, `failed_when`, `changed_when`, `with_items`, `with_dict`, etc expect a variable, so you don't have to use `{{ }}`, in all other cases use the double curly brackets.